# Basic Selenium IDE: how to select next value in dropdown list?

Tags: automation, website

Selenium noob here with very little programming experience. I'm trying to automate the gathering of information from a website I use.

Basically, there's a series of clicks I need to make and for every run of the routine, I need to select the next value in a dropdown box. Can anyone point me to an example of a script that does what I'm trying to do? The script basically does this:

1. Go to website
2. Log in
3. A few clicks to get me to the report I want
4. Enter date range
5. Select first value in dropdown box
6. Series of clicks to run/save the report

Then loops back to step 3, selecting the next dropdown value for step 5 every run until the list is complete.

Any examples or tutorials would be really helpful.

Comment: Selenium IDE has quite a few tutorials already around the web that could give you a good start on this. I think starting with watching a few of those and then coming back to SuperUser/StackOverflow with problems you are facing once you've attempted this might be a good idea.

Comment: So I've got two separate test cases, but I still can't figure out the code to tell it to go back and select the next item on the dropdown list. Will keep watching videos and reading forums until I get it. Thanks.